# Error converting varchar to numeric - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework to update and insert into a SQL database.  I have scripted the database to my local development machine and inserts and updates work fine.  However, when I move to our production server I get the message "Error converting varchar to numeric" although I don't have any numeric fields in the table only float and datetime and char.

Anybody have ideas what is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Float is a numeric data type...   The message is generic, not tied to just the numeric data type

Comment: Cheers Sparky. It looks like including single quotation marks in the sql statement was the issue but still don't understand how it worked on a local db?